# Hyper-v backup solution

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor, remote-backup, cloud-bare-metal

> Can I install Hyper-V in Linux? Suppose our Hyper-V Manager install in windows server . Do I able to backup on Linux? What will be the best solution to backup Hyper-V Manager?

Comment: Belongs on Super User or Server Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you have not described the problem clearly or defined your problem. Hyper-V Manager is Microsoft's virtualization management platform and does not support installation on Linux systems, but it can back up with Linux virtual machines(e.g. CentOS RHEL etc.).
reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/supported-guest-os

Answer (score 0):

You can not install Hyper-v on Linux.
To reduce costs you can use Hyper-v server without passing to Windows server and enable the hyper-v feature.
Veeam backup is the most powerful solution to make backups for Hyper-v or vCenter.